# Disable the <img> open/click tracker in AWS SES emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When sending emails through AWS SES (via AWS REST API SendRawEmail), every email has an  HTML tag containing a 1x1 pixel tracker image pointing to awstrack.me. I want to disable this feature as it is causing emails to be classed as spam, particularly with MS Defender email filtering.

I have tried creating a 'Configuration Set' with an Amazon SNS destination in the 'Event destinations' list. I have only ticked 'Hard bounces' in the list of event types, making sure to untick 'Opens' and 'Clicks'. Once saved, I applied the configuration set to the verified domain so that all messages sent from the domain use the rules in the configuration set. However, any email sent from the domain still contains the tracker image.

How can I disable the tracker image permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Found this was due to me having enabled the SES 'Virtual Deliverability Manager' and within there is an option 'Engagement tracking - opens and clicks' which was ticked.  Once I disabled that, the tracking images stopped.